# SQL QUERY For returning all matched values

Tags: mysql

I want to get the specific output from the two Tables

```
Table 1: A 1      Table 2: A Appple
         B 2               A Apollo
         C 3               B Ball
```

The desired output is:

```
Table 3:
A 1 Apple
A 1 Apollo
B 2 Ball
C 3
```

I am new to programming..How should i get the desired result..will left join get me all the matched records from the second table or just one record?

Comment: A left join sounds like a very good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I simple left join

```
 select a.col1, a.col2, b.col2
 from table1 as a left join table 2 as b on a.col1 = b.col1
```